# Nativescript - onItemLoading callback called twice

Tags: nativescript

Have a simple NS/TS page with a ListView - the list is driven by an ObservableArray.

I add 1 entry to the array and the onItemLoading event gets called 2x.

Here's my XML

```html
        <ListView items="{{ dataItems }}"
              itemLoading="{{ onItemLoading }}"
              itemTap="{{ onNoteTap }}"
              itemTemplateSelector="'note'">

        <ListView.itemTemplates>
            <template key="note">
              <StackLayout>
                    <Label id="label"/>
              </StackLayout>
            </template>

          </ListView.itemTemplates>
        </ListView>
```

Here's my model class

```html
export class NotesModel extends observable.Observable
{
    public _listItemArray: ObservableArray<NoteItem>;

    constructor()
    {
        super();

        this._listItemArray = new ObservableArray<NoteItem>();

        let item = new NoteItem();

        item.label = "test";

        this._listItemArray.push( item );
    }

    get dataItems(): ObservableArray<NoteItem>
    {
        return this._listItemArray;
    }

    onItemLoading( args: listviewModule.ItemEventData )
    {
        console.log( "onItemLoading =" + args.index + " " + args.view );
    }

    onNoteTap( args )
    {
    }
}
```

After I run the code, I get:

JS: constructor

JS: onItemLoading =0 StackLayout(217)@file:///app/my-notes-page.xml:39:15;

JS: onItemLoading =0 StackLayout(217)@file:///app/my-notes-page.xml:39:15;

Answer (score 0):

This is your xml file

```
<ListView items="{{ dataItems }}"
    itemLoading="onItemLoading"
    itemTap="{{ onNoteTap }}"
    itemTemplateSelector="'note'">

<ListView.itemTemplates>
  <template key="note">
    <StackLayout>
          <Label id="label"/>
    </StackLayout>
  </template>

</ListView.itemTemplates>
</ListView>
```

This is your **main.ts** file code, its not the model ts

```
import { EventData } from 'data/observable';
import { Page } from 'ui/page';
import { HelloWorldModel } from './main-view-model';

// Event handler for Page "navigatingTo" event attached in main-page.xml
export function navigatingTo(args: EventData) {

    let page = <Page>args.object;

    page.bindingContext = new HelloWorldModel();
}
export function onItemLoading(args) {
    console.log('Calling here ');
}
```

Comment: I believe what I wrote is valid - the model method onItemLoading is being called. Just for testing, I made it a page method - and it's being called 2x. Can you add 1 entry to the ListView in the HelloWorldModel constructor and see what happens.

Comment: I downloaded it and ran it. The onItemLoading() method is being called 16 times - page getting refreshed 4x. I am using NS 2.5.3 with core 3.0.1 and android 3.1.1.

Comment: please use latest native script. I have written it for NS 3.0